# How to compare array value with variable value

Tags: php

```
 <?php
function try(){

$tutorial = array("D","C","B","A");
for( $i = 0 ; $i < count($tutorial) ; $i++ ){
    if( $tutorial[$i] == 'A' )
        $enum = 1;
    else if( $tutorial[$i] == 'B' )
        $enum = 2;
    else if( $tutorial[$i] == 'C' )
        $enum = 3;
    else if( $tutorial[$i] == 'D' )
        $enum = 4;
    echo "$enum". "<br/>";
}
  ?>
```

When I print out the variable ENUM, it's always blank..
What's is the problem?

Comment: You're getting confused between the assignment operator `=` and the equality operator `==`

Comment: What does this have to do with HTML?

Comment: i print it with html . it's same algorithm. please think it my question twice before post the comment

Comment: How are you not getting an `unexpected 'try' (T_TRY)`?

Comment: The way your question is written, `$tutorial` is null.

Comment: @FeliciaTan - `$tutorial` is out of scope in the function, too.

Comment: @FeliciaTan see my edited answer.. you are not calling the function....

Answer (score 0):

Try this. When you have a condition like `if` use a [comparison](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) operator like `==` not an [asignment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) like `=`

```
$tutorial = array ('A', 'B','B', 'B', 'C', 'D');
for( $i = 0 ; $i < count($tutorial) ; $i++ ){
        if ($tutorial[$i] == 'A') {
            $enum = 1;
        }
        else if( $tutorial[$i] == 'B' ) {
            $enum = 2;
        }
        else if( $tutorial[$i] == 'C' ) {
            $enum = 3;
        }
        else if( $tutorial[$i] == 'D' ){
            $enum = 4;
        }
        echo $enum;
    }

// prints 122234
```

Comment: is same actually. i dont know what is happenning . i get the same result.. why?

Comment: @Felicia Tan where are you printing the enum? If you are printing it at the end it will take the last value from the loop.

Comment: inside the looping. so for example if count = 4:

my output should be something like
3
2
1
4

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using a comparison operator in your `if` statement.  The way you have it written, you are assigning the value `'A'` to `$tutorial[$i]` every single time through the loop.  You need to use `==` or `===`, like this:

```
<?php
function try(){
    for( $i = 0 ; $i < count($tutorial) ; $i++ ) {
        if ( $tutorial[$i] == 'A' ) {
            $enum = 1;
        } elseif ( $tutorial[$i] == 'B' ) {
            $enum = 2;
        } elseif ( $tutorial[$i] == 'C' ) {
            $enum = 3;
        } elseif( $tutorial[$i] == 'D' ) {
            $enum = 4;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

`==` compares values without checking type

`===` compares values and types

Incidentally, I don't see how you're getting the `$tutorial` variable into your function.  You're not passing it in and you're not using `global`.  In which scope does `$tutorial` exist?  Because that could very well be the problem as well (if changing the `=` to `==` doesn't work).

Comment: still cant.... blank answer

Comment: changed my question why it's still same then?

Comment: @FeliciaTan I don't know - http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/du0-xcc according to that link, YOUR code prints the expected output of 4 3 2 1.

Comment: @Crontab it seems he hasn't called the function.....

Answer (score 0):

Your operators are incorrect within the `if` statements, as you are assigning (`=`) the variables and not comparing (`==` or `===`). Also, you're using a reserved word [try](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) (it's reserved for exceptions), which should be causing you all sorts of errors. Something like this should work:

```
function _try(){
    for($i = 0 ;$i < count($tutorial) ;$i++){
        if($tutorial[$i] == "A")
            $enum = 1;
        else if($tutorial[$i] == "B")
            $enum = 2;
        else if($tutorial[$i] == "C")
            $enum = 3;
        else if($tutorial[$i] == "D")
            $enum = 4;
    }
}
```

Or you could always use the control structure [switch()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) to parse through the loop:

```
function _try() {
    for($i = 0 ;$i < count($tutorial) ;$i++){
        switch($tutorial[$i]) {
            case("A"):
                $enum = 1;
                break;
            case("B"):
                $enum = 2;
                break;
            case("C"):
                $enum = 3;
                break;
            case("D"):
                $enum = 4;
                break;
            default:
                $enum = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got three things wrong in your code

1. `try` (`catch`) keyword was used as function name in your code, change the name to something else.
2. missing a brace `}`, ok that could be a typo.
3. Logical error, you have used `=` instead of `==` or `===`

Your now code becomes:

```
 <?php
function tryThis(){
for( $i = 0 ; $i < count($tutorial) ; $i++ ){
    if( $tutorial[$i] == 'A' )
        $enum = 1;
    else if( $tutorial[$i] == 'B' )
        $enum = 2;
    else if( $tutorial[$i] == 'C' )
        $enum = 3;
    else if( $tutorial[$i] == 'D' )
        $enum = 4;
}
}
  ?>
```

**EDIT:**
 Answer for edited question....

It seems you have forgot to call the function....... That change made it working for me.

```
    <?php
    function tryThis(){

    $tutorial = array("D","C","B","A");
    for( $i = 0 ; $i < count($tutorial) ; $i++ ){
        if( $tutorial[$i] == 'A' )
            $enum = 1;
        else if( $tutorial[$i] == 'B' )
            $enum = 2;
        else if( $tutorial[$i] == 'C' )
            $enum = 3;
        else if( $tutorial[$i] == 'D' )
            $enum = 4;
        echo "$enum". "<br/>";
    }


   tryThis();     //functional cal here
      ?>
```